# about security settings of plone control panel

Tags: plone

There are lot of configuration options on plone control panel, for example "security settings".
I need to pre-set for checking "enable user folders " option, it should be immediately effect when a plone site created.

How do I configure control panel settings from a generic setup profile?

Answer (score 3):

It's often a good idea to create a policy product that'll be installed to initialize your site. In your case, your policy product would only have a GS profile.

To get what you're asking, the easiest way would be to simply, make the change on a vallina plone site, then export the GS settings of your site and then use that in your product.

To export the current settings for your site:

1. go to the zmi(append /manage onto site url)
2. go to portal_setup
3. go to export tab
4. scroll down and click to export all profiles

Answer (score 1):

You import a changed version of the "controlpanel.xml" GenericSetup file.  Some details on the controlpanel.xml file are at http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/generic-setup/reference/control-panel, and the general procedure for working with GenericSetup is at http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/generic-setup.  You also may find http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/genericsetup.html helpful.

Comment: Note that controlpanel.xml is for registering the control panels themselves rather than the settings which they set. The setting for creating user folders is in either the membership or memberdata tool IIRC, and can be set in a GS xml file for that tool.